# Unable to add buttons around an image

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code i used to in coding HTML:

```
<button id="imageshow" style="display:none">Button1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="imageshow" style="display:none">Button2</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="imageshow" style="display:none">Button3</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
<img src="Images/Image1.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)"><br>
<button id="imageshow" style="display:none">Button4</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="imageshow" style="display:none">Button5</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="imageshow" style="display:none">Button6</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

When i coded this without using style="display:none", i am able to add everything fine. But when i coded like above and used the below javascript:

```
function showIt(imgsrc)
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').src=imgsrc;
document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='';
}

function hideIt()
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='none';
}
```

Only one button is being added. Can anyone resolve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the same id, so Javascript only takes the first one. Use `class="imageshow"` instead and will be ok.

The script would look like this:

```
function showIt(imgsrc)
{
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName('imageshow');

    for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++)
    {
        images[i].src=imgsrc;
        images[i].style.display='';
    }
}

function hideIt()
{
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName('imageshow');

    for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++)
    {
        images[i].style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Comment: I also have another problem: Now onmouseover all 6 buttons are being displayed and are staying even on mouseout. How to solve this problem

Comment: @aadi you need to update the `hideIt()` function as well, i've edited the answer to show that

Comment: I've updated my javascript code as you've given. But the buttons aren't disappearing. Please help me out. I've been trying this since yesterday

Comment: @aadi When do you want to hide the buttons? Right now there's no call to hideIt() in the code.

Comment: When i hover my mouse, i am able to click the buttons now. If i don't click the buttons and move my cursor out of the buttons, they should disappear

Answer (score 2):

That's because you can only have ONE element with a given id.

You should use classes.

See http://jsfiddle.net/mwu4M/

HTML

Romove those ugly `&nbsp;` and `<br />`. And use `class="imageshow"` instead of `id="imageshow"`.

```
<button class="imageshow">Button1</button>
<button class="imageshow">Button2</button>
<button class="imageshow">Button3</button>
<img id="myimg" src="Images/Image1.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)" onmouseout="hideIt()" alt="[IMG]">
<button class="imageshow">Button4</button>
<button class="imageshow">Button5</button>
<button class="imageshow">Button6</button>
```

CSS:

```
.imageshow{
    visibility:hidden;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.imageshow.show{
    visibility:visible;
}
#myimg{display:block;}
```

JavaScript:

```
function getElementsByClassName(c,el){
    if(typeof el=='string'){el=document.getElementById(el);}
    if(!el){el=document;}
    if(el.getElementsByClassName){return el.getElementsByClassName(c);}
    var arr=[],
        allEls=el.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i=0;i<allEls.length;i++){
        if(allEls[i].className.split(' ').indexOf(c)>-1){arr.push(allEls[i])}
    }
    return arr;
}
function addClass(el,c){
    var arr=el.className.split(' ');
    if(arr.indexOf(c)>-1){return;}
    arr.push(c);
    el.className=arr.join(' ');
}
function delClass(el,c){
    var arr=el.className.split(' ');
    if(arr.indexOf(c)===-1){return;}
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(c),1);
    el.className=arr.join(' ');
}
function showIt(imgsrc){
    this.src=imgsrc;
    var els=getElementsByClassName('imageshow');
    for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
        addClass(els[i],'show');
    }
}
function hideIt(){
    var els=getElementsByClassName('imageshow');
    for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
        delClass(els[i],'show');
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Or even better: http://jsfiddle.net/mwu4M/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <button class="imageshow">Button1</button>
    <button class="imageshow">Button2</button>
    <button class="imageshow">Button3</button>
    <img id="myimg" src="Images/Image1.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)" onmouseout="hideIt()" alt="[IMG]">
    <button class="imageshow">Button4</button>
    <button class="imageshow">Button5</button>
    <button class="imageshow">Button6</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper>.imageshow{
    visibility:hidden;
    margin-right:15px;
}
#wrapper.show>.imageshow{
    visibility:visible;
}
#myimg{display:block;}
```

JavaScript:

```
function showIt(imgsrc){
    this.src=imgsrc;
    document.getElementById('wrapper').className="show";
}
function hideIt(){
    document.getElementById('wrapper').className="";
}
```

But I don't understand what you do with `src`.

Your code had

```
document.getElementById('imageshow').src=imgsrc;
```

but `imageshow` were buttons instead of images!

Then I thought you wanted to change `myimg`' src.

But it doesn't make sense because we change its `src` to its `src`!!

```
<img id="myimg" src="Images/Image1.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)" onmouseout="hideIt()" alt="[IMG]">
function showIt(imgsrc){
    this.src=imgsrc;/*It was "Images/Image1.jpg" and now it's "Images/Image1.jpg" too*/
    document.getElementById('wrapper').className="show";
}
```

**Edit 2:**

If you want to show the buttons when you hover the image and hide them when the mouse goes to another place, you can use `onmouseleave` on the parent. But that it's not supported by all browsers, so you need to implement it:

```
function containsOrIs(el1,el2){
    if(el1===el2){return true;}
    return Boolean(el1.compareDocumentPosition(el2)&16);
}
function addEvent(el,e,f,b){
    if(typeof el==='string'){el=document.getElementById(el);}
    if(e=='mouseenter'||e=='mouseleave'){
        return addEvent(el,e=='mouseenter'?'mouseover':'mouseout',function(e){
            if(!e){e=window.event;}
            if((el===e.target || containsOrIs(el, e.target)) && !containsOrIs(el, e.relatedTarget||e[e=='mouseenter'?'fromElement' : 'toElement'])){
                f();
            }
        });
    }
    if(el.addEventListener){
        if(b==undefined){b=false}
        return el.addEventListener(e,f,b);
    }
    if(el.attachEvent){
        return el.attachEvent('on'+e,f);
    }
}
function showIt(imgsrc){
    this.src=imgsrc;
    document.getElementById('wrapper').className="show";
}
function hideIt(){
    document.getElementById('wrapper').className="";
}
window.onload=function(){
    addEvent('wrapper','mouseleave',hideIt);
}
```

[**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/mwu4M/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/mwu4M/2/)

**Edit 3**:

But maybe you prefer using `:hover`, it's simplier and CSS-only:

```
#wrapper>.imageshow{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#wrapper:hover>.imageshow{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

But then the buttons will be shown when the mouse hovers `#wrapper`, not only the image.

[**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/mwu4M/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mwu4M/3/)

Comment: The reason why i gave same id is all the button's should be displayed when mouse is over the image

Comment: This doesn't matter @aadi, ID's are singular and **cannot** be repeated. period. this isn't a recommendation it's how things work.

Comment: Thank u. But i also want to click the button's which is not possible with the code you've given. But anyway i've achieved it by the code given by mornaner. Now i want to disable them when the cursor crosses the position of buttons. Is that possible

Comment: @aadi With my code you can't click the buttons because of `onmouseout="hideIt()"`, which I added because you had a function `hideIt` but you didn't call it. I don't understand what do you mean with *when the cursor crosses the position of buttons*

Comment: Ok. Let me explain, Im now able to click buttons by modifying the showIt() method. If don't click the buttons after onmouseover and move the mouse to somewhere else in the browser, buttons should disappear

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` will only return one element (as specs says ID should be unique) and so wont apply to all your buttons.

Your alternatives are to replace your IDs with Names and use `document.getElementsByName()` or classes however selecting elements by class in a cross broweser way isn't too simple unless your ok with including a library such as jQuery on your page.